# TypeError: ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedJsonSync is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I'm trying to run this piece of code to deploy a smart contract in JS with ethers.js library:

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
require("dotenv").config();

async function main() {
  const provider = new ethers.ethers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.RPC_URL);
  // reads the json private key from file
  const encryptedJson = fs.readFileSync("./.encryptedKey.json", "utf-8");
  
// ========= START FAILING PART ============
  let wallet = new ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedJsonSync(
    encryptedJson,
    process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD
  );
// ========= END FAILING PART ============
  
  wallet = await wallet.connect(provider);
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf-8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf-8"
  );
  
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy({ gasPrice: 1000000000000 });
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

but I keep getting this error in the console:

```
TypeError: ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedJsonSync is not a constructor
at main (/home/vituz01/hh/ethers-simple-storage/deploy.js:36:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vituz01/hh/ethers-simple-storage/deploy.js:90:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1239:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1293:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:935:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:84:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

Can someone explain why this is failing? I think I'm calling the function fromEncryptedJsonSync() correctly (as explained in the EthersJS v5 docs, see the following link: [ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedJsonSync](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/signer/#Wallet-fromEncryptedJsonSync)); I couldn't find the ethers.js v6 docs since they are still building it.

Answer (score 7):

Remove new as it creates a constructor

```js
let wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedJsonSync(
  encryptedJson,
  process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD
);
```